# Rewritebase domains Godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a account in GoDaddy where i can add so much domains as i want.

So  i have created a folder in the root with the name `_Domains`, and inside of this folder i put all the domains, like this structure.

`_Domains/example.com` <- Folder of the domain `example.com`

The problem is this.

I trying to install one live helper and i get this URL on the form action of the installer.

```
<form action="/_Domains/example.com/consulta/index.php/site_admin/install/install/2" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

But i need this kind of url `<form action="example.com/consulta.....` and so on..

Is there a possible to do that with htaccess? I will apreciate your help.

Comment: Its not clear. Can you clarify whats you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you are _really_ taking about service separate _domains_, then both form action urls do not make sense. You'd need either a url like `https://example.com/consulta/index.php/site_admin/...` or an absolute path like `/consulta/index.php/site_admin/...` or a relative path, probably `index.php/site_admin/...` in this case.